# newton raphson method- root outside the interval

Tags: calculus

I am using Newton Raphson method to show that there is a root in the interval [-2,0]

$f(x)=x^4 + x^2+8x-1 $

then we need:

$ f(x)=0$

so: $x^4 + x^2+8x-1=0$

the derivative is $f'(x)= 4x^3+2x+8$

I performed all the calculations and my initial value is x=-1 which give me a root outside the interval I want.

The result will converge for x=0.123 (3dp) which is not in the interval [-2,0]

I was reading and I found that if the initial value is too far away from the root, we will end up to find another root, that was what I got.

Can anyone explain me if there is anything that I can do to find the root in the interval [-2,0] with the initial value x=-1 or do I need to change the initial value to obtain the root I need?

Thank you,

Comment: The algorithm is deterministic, so whenever you run it with an initial value of $-1$, you will land at the same zero. You need to change the algorithm or the initial value to find a zero in $[-2,0]$.

Comment: Try the initial value -2.

Comment: You do not need NR to show that there is a root in the interval. The fact that $f(x)$ changes signs between $x=-2$ and $x=0$ is sufficient to show that there is at least one root in the interval. Sketching the curve $y=f(x)$ over the interval indicates the root is near $x=-1.9$, so start there.